# One list is not properly saved within another, Python, networkx

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to create an adjacency matrix, for a graph of variable size.

This is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import graphviz
from networkx.algorithms.operators.product import _init_product_graph
from networkx.classes.function import edges, info
from networkx.drawing import nx_agraph
from networkx.generators.trees import prefix_tree
import os
from os import remove
G = nx.DiGraph()

lista=[]

Columnas=[]
Filas=[]

def correr():
  listaFinal=[]
  G.add_node("Daniel")
  G.add_node("Javier")
  G.add_node("Kimberly")
  G.add_node("Fernando")

  G.add_edge("Daniel", "Javier")
  G.add_edge("Javier", "Kimberly")
  G.add_edge("Kimberly", "Fernando")


  for i in G.nodes:
    Columnas.append(i)
    Filas.append(i)

  
  for i in range(len(Columnas)):
    lista.append("0")
  print(lista)
  x=0
  for i in Filas:
    for edge in G.edges:
      for j in Columnas:
      
        
        if ((i==edge[0] and j == edge[1]) or (i==edge[1] and j == edge[0])):
          lista[x]="1"
        x+=1
      
      x=0
    
    
    print("Lista a guardar: " + str(lista))
    listaFinal.append(lista)
    print("Se vuelven 0 otra vez")
    
    
  
    for i in range(len(lista)):
      lista[i]="0"
  print(listaFinal)

 
  
if __name__=="__main__":
  correr()
```

But when printing the final matrix it is printed like this:

```
['0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0']
```

and it should be printed this way:

```
['0', '1', '0', '0']
['1', '0', '1', '0']
['0', '1', '0', '1']
['0', '0', '1', '0']
```

I have noticed that the error occurs in this area of ​​my code:

```
print("Lista a guardar: " + str(lista))
listaFinal.append(lista)
```

Since when adding the small list to the larger one, it is not entered correctly.

It is only entered with 0

```
['0', '0', '0', '0']
```

I have reviewed and I do not know why it fails.

Any idea why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your issue, you can simply use the build in functions, e.g. [`adjacency_matrix`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.graphmatrix.adjacency_matrix.html) or [`to_numpy_array`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.to_numpy_array.html?highlight=numpy#networkx.convert_matrix.to_numpy_array).

Since you seem to look for the symmetric adjacency matrix, the following should work:

```
adjacency = nx.to_numpy_array(G.to_undirected())
```

If you anyways want to continue with your own code, you currently always reset `lista` to all `"0"` with the following lines

```
for i in range(len(lista)):
      lista[i]="0"
```

This could be solved in a quick and dirty way by always appending copies:

```
listaFinal.append(lista[:])
```